# rsync script doubles the content instead adding it into correct directory, adds question mark into the directory name

Tags: rsync

I am not sure what could have gone wrong with my rsync script I use to beckup data from one server to another. The issue is that when the script is run by cron, it creates an additional directory, for example domains? root?c, it adds question mark at the end of the directory names and stars copying the content into these directories instead of copying it into domains or root (without question mark).

It used to work fine, then I tried to add bandwidth limitaion and not I am getting this issue which is quite bothering cause the HDD used for backup adds up pretty fast as now the rsync script is copying and backing up all the content into new directories it creates once again instead of just adding the data into the directoires where it should be.

Following is the rsync script I am using:

```
rsync -a --bwlimit=5000 --delete -e "ssh -p 123 -q" 10.24.124.20:/home/common/ /Zarchiv/plesk1/home/common
rsync -a --bwlimit=5000 --delete -e "ssh -p 123 -q" 10.24.124.20:/home/mysql/ /Zarchiv/plesk1/home/mysql
find /Zarchiv/plesk1/home/mysql -type f -ctime +3 -exec rm {} \; 

rsync -a --bwlimit=5000 --delete -e "ssh -p 123 -q" 10.24.124.20:/home/root/ /Zarchiv/plesk1/root
rsync -a --bwlimit=5000 --delete -e "ssh -p 123 -q" 10.24.124.20:/home/domains/ /Zarchiv/plesk1/domains


find /Zarchiv/plesk1 -name "access_log" -exec rm {} \;
find /Zarchiv/plesk1 -name "access_log.processed*" -exec rm {} \;
find /Zarchiv/plesk1 -name "error_log" -exec rm {} \;
find /Zarchiv/plesk1 -name "error_log.*" -exec rm {} \;
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with an rsync backup script. Turned out that the script had DOS-style newlines (CRLF) in it. When I converted the newlines to UNIX-style (LF) with dos2unix the problem disappeared.

Comment: It seems that the '?' character is rsync's way of representing the character, '\r'.  A simpler fix is to add a space at end of the line with the rsync command in your script.  This leaves you with a script file you can edit with Windows text editors.